# Duplicate Rule does not block Contacts with the same email

Tags: duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

In our Salesforce org, the duplicate rules to block a user from creating a Contact with the same email as another Contact are quite flaky.  About .02% of our Contacts are duplicates as a result of users not receiving a warning about the other Contact with the same email address.

I've attached a screenshot of the rule - is there something obvious I'm missing? (This is rule 4/5 and the first 3 rules are Inactive)

[image: Duplicate rule]

Comment: have you analyzed how those .02% of your contacts were created? possibly through duplicates that were inserted in the same batch through a data load? Inserted/updated records are only compared with what records are already in Salesforce - see [considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_overview.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for this!  It wasn't batch loads but I did notice the rules are ignored if `Records are created using Quick Create or Community Self-Registration.` which seems a bit crazy to me, but I'll investigate that route!